# changing password ldapmodify over SSL to AD 2008 R2 fails with 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1248, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM)

Tags: ssl, active-directory, ldap, openldap

When attempting an `ldapmodify` to set the unicode password (with the correct encoding) over SSL(636), the operation fails and Active Directory returns the following error code:

> 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A1248, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data
>   0

I found countless threads and answers on resolving `WILL_NOT_PERFORM` but I am hoping someone knows the meaning of the exact codes above.

Every other solution points to password complexity, min pw age before the modify, SSL requirement, encoding requirement, and some others.

We have set the min pw age to 0, ensured we met the pw complexity requirements, encoded in UTF16LE=>base64, submitted the operation over SSL with 256 bit encryption and trusted/verified certificates, and we still receive this message.

The `ldapadds`/`modifies` are being performed by an automated tool which has successfully worked on other AD 2008 R2 instances so we know the password reqs, encodings, and SSL requirements are satisfied by the tool.  We also tested with manual `ldapmodify` via LDIF and receive the same message.

Can anyone shed some light on any other possible permission, bug, UAC related setting, or way to decrypt the exact error code above?

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated! :)

Comment: Show us some code. Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I could only guess about your environment setup, but try to perform these steps:

- Check if this password really could be setup through AD interface on server
- Ensure you wrap you password with double quotes before encoding (i.e. it should be `"password"`, not `password`
- Check if you use `unicodePwd` attribute to set the password

So my ldapmodify entry to set password to `StrongPassword!` looks like:

```
dn: CN=User,CN=Users,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=org
changetype: modify
replace: unicodePwd
unicodePwd:: IgBTAHQAcgBvAG4AZwBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAIQAiAA==
```

Note `unicodePwd` has two colons